# create file on localhost (Web server physical path)

Tags: c#, asp.net

Currently I am working on **asp.net** website and I am not very much familiar with asp.net. I have a `WebForm` and when user clicks on **Submit** button a `.txt` file should be get created on server(Text File name is ID entered by user which is unique.)
I used following to create the file.

```
File.Create( Server.MapPath("~") + id + @".txt");
```

But this gives me error when the site is running on the localhost of my pc.
**Access to the path 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\XXX\YYY.txt' is denied.**

This is something related with access permission. What should I do to fix this. Please advice me.

Comment: Wont work on windows 7. Try changing the drive nd it will work.

Answer (score 2):

Add write permission for NETWORK SERVICE to the folder in question.

Comment: To the wwwRoot or XXX folder?

Comment: Tried that but same error comes.Is it ok to set this to wwwRoot?

Comment: What OS/IIS and version of ASP.NET are you using?

Comment: I am using Windows 7, IIS 7  and .net 3.5.
It seems to be working if I give the write access to IIS user.

Comment: As I mentioned above I was able to fix my issue by giving accesss to the iis user. Thanks for the clue you gave which helped to fix my issue. Thanks for the support and quick response. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
File.Create(@"\\127.0.0.1\www\test\test.txt");
```